# Number of $10$ step paths from the top to bottom of a “Pascal diamond”

Tags: combinatorics

My question pertains to a topic in class notes from a course given by Polya and Tarjan. Notes were generously produced by Donald Woods

Here is a link (my apologies in that I don’t know how to format it so it looks nice) [https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/Combo20/PTW.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/Combo20/PTW.pdf)

(A question that explicitly deals with the course discussion but is not my question is here [How many different paths from top to bottom spell ALGEBRA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687146/how-many-different-paths-from-top-to-bottom-spell-algebra))

The answer of the linked question gets at what I’m interested in.

Given a $11$ row diamond with vertices following a Pascal type lattice, how many $10$ step paths are there from top to bottom.

As the notes and linked question details, one can solve it by hand or recognize it as a Pascal type calculation of cumulative addition from the two preceding nodes.

But at last my question:

Just using powers of $2$,you can calculate the number of paths through the center row as $2^5=32$.

But can you proceed using powers of $2$ making suitable deletions to get to the correct answer of $252$?

What I’ve tried is taking the different between each successive lower row’s total as if it was a replete Pascal triangle and the correct total in the diminished row of the diamond.

And tried, without success, to find some method adjusting powers of $2$ to get to the right answer.

Visually you have a big $11$ row Pascal triangle with two triangles removed on the right and left to give the appropriate diamond shape,

So maybe the answer lies in that,

Thanks

Comment: Is it even very helpful to know there are $2^5 = 32$ ways to get to the center row, since there are different numbers of ways to get to the different points on that row, and different numbers of ways to get from those points to the bottom point?

Comment: @aschepler (like the handle) if I’m not mistaken, I think that’s covered with the $10$ step constraint. Also you can see the relevance perhaps in the answer to the linked question. But naively, at any node you can drop left or right.

Comment: I see 5 ones from the regular Pascal's Triangle in that image; then it goes down another 5 steps to reach 252. I'd check whether the final number is provably C(5+5,5) = C(10,5) = 252 in a more general setting. I'm guessing this will be more fruitful than powers of 2 (unless a very contrived answer is satisfying).

Comment: Yes, there are $2^5$ ways to get to the 6th row of Pascal's triangle, and $2^{10}$ ways to get to the 11th row, not all of which land in the center ${10 \choose 5}$ entry. But imagine that something other than the normal grid gave 32 different ways in total to reach a row of six entries - that's not enough information to say how many ways there are to continue on to the bottom of the lower triangle!

Comment: You can think of all $2^{10}$ paths to the 11th row of the full triangle, with some of those paths "falling off" the edge of the diamond. At the entry ${7 \choose 2} = 21$, $21$ of those paths "fall off" the left side. What does this have to do with powers of two? If you find an answer, I don't think it will be a simple intuitive one.

Comment: But one clever thing we can do here: At each point on the center row, the number of ways to get from the top to that point is the same as the number of ways to get from that point to the bottom. So the total number of paths through that point is the square of that number. And the total number of valid paths overall is $1^2 + 5^2 + 10^2 + 10^2 + 5^2 + 1^2 = 252$.